# Can you say "events that have impacted their lives"

Tags: grammar

Can you say the characters are struggling with "events that have impacted their lives" or would you have to say events that have impacted **on** their lives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct. You could also phrase it "the characters are struggling with the events that have had an impact on their lives," which sounds a little wordy and stuffy to me.